# How to delete a form from the Object Repository

Tags: delphi

[image]I am on Delphi Berlin and I am unable to delete a form I previously added to the standard RAD Studio Object Repository.

If I click on Tools, Template Libraries then I click on RAD Studio Object Repository and then Properties button, I can see the form I previously added to a custom created folder that is a subfolder of the Delphi Files folder.

To me, it seems that it is impossible to delete a form once you have added it to the RAD Studio Object Repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Template libraries, when you navigate to the folder where you placed your Repository item, once you select the item, on the RHS you should see `Edit` and `Delete` buttons as in the screenshot below.  If you don't, please add a screenshot of what you *do* see to your q.

[image: Object Repository editor]

Comment: Just edited my original post: thank you so much MartynA! your screenshot pointed me to doublecheck my screen settings. In screen resolution settings I have previously changed the default text size from 100% (Default) to 125%. As you can see in my screenshot I had no Edit nor Delete buttons. Switching back to text size 100% solved my issue. Anyway this is a bug IMHO.